# How to set Alarms on the DS3231 easily so the Nano doesn't have to go to sleep with delay statements?

Tags: rtc, ds3231-alarms

I want my solar array sun tracker to shut down at night then move full east in the morning to catch the first rays.

I know the DS3231 can set alarms but it is not clear from its documentation how to do it with the normal library.

Delay statements are the way I have it periodically check for when to take readings, but I really want it to be able to respond to radio-remote control commands, which don't work during delays.

Q:  Is there an easier way?

Comment: Which library are you using? As [this one supports it just fine](https://github.com/JChristensen/DS3232RTC/blob/master/DS3232RTC.h#L142-L145).

Comment: That is interesting.  Will bookmark it.  Thanks, @Gerben

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33972/how-to-have-some-code-executed-at-a-certain-time-of-day-with-a-ds3231-rtc/33973#33973

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

https://github.com/sleemanj/DS3231_Simple

Example:  https://github.com/sleemanj/DS3231_Simple/blob/master/examples/z2_Alarms/Alarm/Alarm.ino

This is what I was looking for.

My system needs to be able to respond to radio remote commands while asleep, and the long delay() statements were preventing that.

These alarms solve the problem.